# Datagrid headers scrollable with empty datagrid wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, datagrid

how can i set my datagrid scrollable when is empty?

I digged up a little and find out that my datagrid tamplate is:

```
  <DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter
  x:Name="PART_ColumnHeadersPresenter"
  Grid.Column="1"
  Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility,
  ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Column},
  Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, 
  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />

  <ScrollContentPresenter
   x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter"
   Grid.Row="1"
   Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
   CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" />

  <Grid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1">
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding NonFrozenColumnsViewportHorizontalOffset,
   RelativeSource= {RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
  <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ScrollBar
        x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
        Orientation="Horizontal"
        ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"
        Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
        Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
  </Grid>
```

Is there a way to add CanContentScroll to my DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter, or set ScrollContentPresenter that it doesn't become disabled when the grid become empty?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, have you tried to set parent control MaxHeight or Height ?

Comment: @AliBigdeli yes, already did  it. That's allow scrollbars work when the grid is populated with data.